# Lubridate quesitons with mutate () and formatting

Tags: r, format, lubridate

I am trying to mutate and add a column into my dataframe (Q5P5), the dataframe is as below:

| Year | Month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | 1 | 3.1 |

I want to add a column at the end called "Time" and use the format DMY, i did below code:

`Q5P5_con <- mutate(Q5P5,time =dmy(Q5P5$Month))`

the console gave this warning message:

Problem while computing `time = dmy(b2q2$month)`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

How shall i solve this?

Comment: Perhaps `Q5P5_con <- mutate(Q5P5,time =dmy(paste(1, Month, Year))` or  `Q5P5_con <- mutate(Q5P5,time =make_date(Year, Month))`

Comment: Thanks @RicVillalba. I worked around it and did something similar. I'm getting results at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a a column whit month and year, try this:

```
Q5P5_con <- Q5P5 %>%
     mutate(time = my(paste0(Month, "-", Year))
```